# The Conversion Between Dates and Strings in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime

I worked now in a dynamic ASP.NET C# web application that connects to a Sybase database using ODBC and my main problem is the conversion between datetime and string data types in my application.

The database saves the datetime data in the following form:-

```
7/11/2011 05:05:05
I think it is in the pattern of "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
```

I need to call a web service and pass some datetime parameters to get the correct output.
The static datetime format that is accepted by the web service is:-

```
11/07/11 09:09:09
I think it is in the pattern of "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss"
```

I tried using the following functions separately

```
string s = d.toString(string format)
DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(string s)
DateTime d = s.Datetime.Parse(string format)
DateTime d = s.Datetime.ParseExact(string format)
```

to convert the dates I got from the database to be suitable to be passed to the web service but it always gives me different exceptions like:-

Exception:System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles) at System.DateTime.Parse(String s) at WebApplication1.WebForm1.callWebservice()

I do not know how I should use and convert dates in the proper way and I get disappointed as I try many examples and functions but I can not get the right methodlogy.

I hope that I find someone who could help and Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow the link, there's everything about DateTime Formatting:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I discovered that my computer system date and time format should bein the same format as the web service and my conversion functions were working fine but the System converts it again to another format when I call Convert.toDateTime() when passing the parameter to the web service. Anyhow, thanks for your useful web link that has about all date/time formats in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `DateTime.ParseExact`

Try the following `DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("11/07/11 09:09:09", "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss", null);`

Answer (score 0):

does your webservice expect a string or an actual datetime object?

Have you tried passing the date time in the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` as this format should be universally recognised?